# How to make list and paragraph inline and float right?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble making my list inline along with the

Sign In

to the right of it. I tried putting float for the  tags since every part on my header is a link, but that isn't working. Can anyone help me put the logo float left, the list to the right, with the sign in being the farthest thing right (float right pretty much for the sign in). Thanks for any answers I get, I truly appreciate it.

html:

```
<header>
  <nav id="header-flex">

    <div>
      <img src="logo.jpg" alt=logo width="30px" height="30px">
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="___">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="___">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="___">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="___">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p><a href="___">Sign In</a></p>
    </div>

  </nav>
</header>
```

css:

```
#header-flex {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgb(0,191,255);
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;

}

header a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by giving your div's a width and assigning 'float: left' to them, like this:

HTML:

```
    <div class="left">
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="30px" height="30px">
    </div>

    <div class="mid">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="___">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="___">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="___">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="___">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <p><a href="___">Sign In</a></p>
    </div>

</nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#header-flex {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgb(0, 191, 255);
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
}

header a {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.left, .mid, .right {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but worth mentioning is that because you assigned 'float: right' to `header a`, you'll see your links go to the right of the right of their div.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I just want to understand what's happening though, so why does making the links float right and the classes float left, put everything where they should be instead of the left? And what purpose does width: 33% serve? I realized it won't work without it, but i'm wondering why it does what it does.

Comment: The width can also be set to px or other percentages. This way you will however get most coverage. Personally, I'd get a fixed width div wrapper and center that and inside of that put those divs with their widths.

Comment: Oh okay makes sense. Could you link me an example of how to effectively make a width div wrapper as I am not sure how it would affect my page.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` has `display: block;` by default, no need to use div for img and ul.

Also, remove the default 8px margin from body:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

A nav is better to use `display: block;` since you want it to take the whole width.

Now you can use `float: left`, `float: right`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#header-flex {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgb(0, 191, 255);
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  float: left;
}

#header-flex>ul {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.sign-in {
  float: right;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav id="header-flex">
    <img src="logo.jpg" alt=logo width="30px" height="30px">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="___">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="___">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="___">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="___">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="sign-in">
      <a href="___">Sign In</a>
    </div>

  </nav>
</header>
```